# How to compute the cross product using cyclindrical coordinates?

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

can anyone help explain what formula could be used to compute the cross product in cylindrical coordinates? Is it the same for Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: There will be a problem for points on the $z$ axis because they do not have a unique $\theta$ in cylindical coordinates $(r, \theta,z).$ But for "most" pairs of vectors in cylindrical coordinates (call the pair $(u,v)$) there is the obvious method: convert to cartesian, compute cross product, convert result back to cylindrical coordinates. Barring the non-uniqueness issue this works. But I don't know if the generic expression ends up at all "nice" if you insist on having the computation go directly from cylindrical to cylindrical, eliminating intermediate steps.

Comment: Thank you @coffeemath, I have very "long horrifying" coordinates that I want to compute the cross product for that's why I was wondering if there was a way to go from cylindrical to cylindrical directly

Comment: The formula for cross product is the same in any right-handed ON basis.

Comment: @coffeemath: What I meant was that the associated frame $(\mathbf{e}_r,\mathbf{e}_\theta,\mathbf{e}_z)$ is right-handed and ON at each point where it's defined, i.e., away from the $z$-axis. And I suppose that if you say that you have two vector fields expressed in cylindrical coordinates, what that actually means is that you know their coordinates with respect to that frame.

Comment: @HansLundmark, does this mean because the frame is a right handed orthonormal plane, the formula for the cross product (for cartesian coordinates) works?

Comment: A fram is not a plane, so I don't quite understand what you mean, but the proof of the coordinate formula for cross products only uses that the basis is right-handed and ON, so yes, the formula is the same.

Comment: @HansLundmark, that makes sense, thank you.